# Как в цикле установить offset или что-то в этом роде

Tags: wordpress, циклы, условия

Здравствуйте посмотрите пожалуйста код ниже. Как видите у меня есть цикл и я хочу чтобы до блока all_s6 выводились только 5 добавленых блоков с помощью цикла остальные блоки при их количестве от 5 и выше выводились в блоке all_s6, которые по идее будет их скрывать, ну чтобы на странице отображалось только 5 блоков а при клике пользователь мог их посмотреть все количество, так вот сторону js я сделал, теперь мне надо только узнать как сделать такой offset заранее спасибо за помощь. Работаю на wordpress и например у записях есть аргумент оффсета что очень удобно.

```
<?php $reviews = carbon_get_theme_option('reviews', 'complex');
        if (!empty($reviews)): ?>
        <div class="items_s6">
            <?php foreach ($reviews as $grab): ?>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="img-wrap">
                    <img src="<?php echo $grab['img_r'] ?>" alt="Отзыв">
                </div>

                <div class="text_s6">
                    <h3><?php echo $grab['fio'] ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $grab['text_r'] ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <div class="all_s6">

        </div>

        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не Wordpress, а обычный PHP. Задаем $num для нумерации цикла и пишем условие:

```
<?php
$reviews = carbon_get_theme_option('reviews', 'complex');

if (!empty($reviews)) {
    $num = 0;
    foreach ($reviews as $grab) {
        $num++
        if ($num <= '5') {
            ?>
            <div class="items_s6">content</div>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="all_s6">all_content</div>
            <?php
        }
    }
} ?>
```